# How important is it to have a clean test suite on CouchDB?

Tags: testing, ubuntu, couchdb, test-suite, ubuntu-11.10

I recently installed CouchDB, but haven't gotten past the **test suite** yet. It seems that each time I run it, I get different errors than before, even without configuration changes.

[The CouchDB Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/tour.html#welcome) says the test suite shouldn't have "an inordinate number of failures", but what is "inordinate"? **How many errors should I tolerate before I start developing?**

---

For reference, here are the errors I'm seeing.

When installed from Ubuntu repository (*Runs 1 & 2*):

- oauth
- replication
- rev_stemming
- security_validation
- view_conflicts

Then remedied by removing, then installing from source, as suggested [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.couchdb.user/16292):

*Run 3*

- attachments
- jsonp

*Runs 4 & 5*

- attachments
- auth_cache
- jsonp
- list_views
- rev_stemming

---

*Run 6, after clearing cache, then restarting couchdb*

- No errors!

Comment: Very interesting that the guide says that. I would guess that if your database install has ANY test failures, you shouldn't use it for anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each test passes individually, you are all set to proceed with development.

The test suite is not as reliable as we'd like due to its dependence on the javascript engine inside the browser and various timing and other issues. It is mostly used to help the developers validate a release.

We are planning to improve this situation in future releases, most likely by moving the test suite out of the browser entirely and running it from a known environment.

If you do want to see all tests pass, then be sure you are using FireFox (the only browser we officially support for running the test suite itself). You might also find it necessary to clear your browser cache too.

Comment: Clearing the cache was an excellent suggestion. After doing so, then restarting couchdb (v1.1.1), I was able to pass all tests. Thanks!